# JavaFX check if it is full screen

Tags: javafx

Hey I want to check if my application is full screen or not I use javafx how can I so do it?

I have tried to getfullscreenexitproperty but that does not work.

Comment: Which Javafx version are you using ?

Comment: The newest one jdk 8

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check this using [isFullScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#isFullScreen()) available in `Stage`

> primaryStage.isFullScreen()

Comment: It doesn't work when u update so how can I fix that?

Comment: Well you should update your question with what you are trying to do and why is it not working for you, if possible add some code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.. if you have button to make your window full screen I've use something like this..

```
@FXML
void onFullScreenExecuted(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) btnFullScreen.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setFullScreen(true);

    if (stage.isFullScreen()) {
        controlBox.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        controlBox.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

and i use this to bring it back the "controlbox" that i've created.(im using undecorated window)

```
 @FXML
void checkFullScreen(KeyEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) btnFullScreen.getScene().getWindow();

    if (stage.isFullScreen()) {
        controlBox.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        controlBox.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

this one is an events from fxml. if the you press esc on your keyboard the control box makes it visible again.. I hope this help..